# Sublime Text 3 - Change color of just one window?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use multiple windows of Sublime Text at once and would like to set each one to a different color theme. By default, changing the 'color preferences' changes them for all open windows.

Note it is possible to set the color scheme for a single window using a 'project settings' file (which suggests it is possible in general), but then the folder must be opened via the 'project settings' (and not just opening the folder).

How can I (programmatically or via the app) set a separate color scheme for a single SublimeText window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a small plugin. Create a new file with Python syntax, and the following contents:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ChangeWindowColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def change_scheme(self, scheme):
        for view in self.window.views():
            view.settings().set("color_scheme", scheme)

    def run(self):
        message = 'Enter path to color scheme:'
        path = 'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme'
        self.window.show_input_panel(message, path, self.change_scheme, None, None)
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` folder (accessible via **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**) as `change_window_color_scheme.py`. You can trigger the plugin in two ways - from the console, and via a key binding. To run it via the console, open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and enter

```py
window.run_command('change_window_color_scheme')
```

An input panel will open at the bottom of the window, where you can enter the path to the color scheme you want to use. The default value is Monokai, but you can change that in the plugin source if you want. Once you enter the path, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and all the files in the current window will use that color scheme.

To create a key binding, open **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and add the following:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "change_window_color_scheme" }
```

If the file is empty, surround the above with square brackets `[ ]`. Save the file, and you can now trigger the plugin using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or whichever key combination works best for you.

Comment: Sweet! This is a major improvement for me for ST3. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm - this affects all open files (tabs), but opening new tabs do not use the new theme...

Comment: I modified @MattDMo 's little plugin above to use a drop-down window and only change color-scheme for the current tab.  Check it out at https://gist.github.com/ebrensi/5209ff45ed094c83cfbb0a14288c982c

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small improvement to the solution provided by @MattDMo as it does not apply the new window color scheme to new tabs. I made no improvement to Efrem's single tab solution at this time, it was just convenient to fork his gist.

To activate it I use CTRL+K+C+K but you can use whatever you want.

[Change Tab or Window color scheme](https://gist.github.com/zitot/5c0e5f1ec42a376f5b3713cacdf6baed)

**Change Window Color Scheme**

```
    import sublime
    import sublime_plugin
    import os

    global_data = {}
    def setWindowColorScheme(window, scheme):
        global_data [window.id()] = scheme

    class ChangeWindowColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

        def run(self):
            window = sublime.active_window()
            view = window.active_view()
            settings = view.settings()

            current_scheme = settings.get('color_scheme', '')
            themes = self.installed_themes()
            names = sorted(themes)
            
            def make_selection(index):
                name = names[index]
                fname = themes[name]
                for view in self.window.views():
                    view.settings().set("color_scheme", fname)
                setWindowColorScheme(window, fname)

            def on_done(index):
                if index == -1:
                    settings.set("color_scheme", current_scheme)
                    return
                make_selection(index)

            window.show_quick_panel(
                names,
                on_done,
                on_highlight=make_selection
            )

        def installed_themes(self):
            scheme_paths = sublime.find_resources('*.tmTheme')
            scheme_paths.extend(
                sublime.find_resources('*.sublime-color-scheme')
            )

            themes = {os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0]: path for path in scheme_paths}
            return themes
```

**Window color scheme event listener**

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

# This module must be paired with change_window_color_scheme.py as it imports global_data, a dict, from that module

class WindowSchemeEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_new(self, view):
        from change_window_color_scheme import global_data
        default_color_scheme = sublime.ui_info()['color_scheme']['value']
        vwid = view.window().id()
        scheme = global_data.get(vwid, default_color_scheme)
        view.settings().set('color_scheme', scheme)

    def on_load(self, view):
        from change_window_color_scheme import global_data
        vwid = view.window().id()
        default_color_scheme = sublime.ui_info()['color_scheme']['value']
        scheme = global_data.get(vwid, default_color_scheme)
        view.settings().set('color_scheme', scheme)
```